# Automate function execution with a loop using metaprogramming

Tags: while-loop, metaprogramming, dolphindb

How can I automate the execution of a series of functions (with the names “test_1”, “test_2“, … “test_100”) using metaprogramming in DolphinDB?

For example:

```
def test_2(){
    return 1
}
eval(<test_2()>)//output: 1
```

I want to use a loop to generate the function names as strings and pass them to `eval` for execution. But when I passed the function name as a string to `eval`, the result is not what I wanted:

```
eval(<'test_2()'>)//output: test_2()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `parseExpr()` to convert the string “test_2()“ into metacode (<test_2()>), then execute it with `eval()`. To automate the execution of all 100 functions, simply write a loop that generates strings of the function names.

Alternatively, you can also use `functionByName` to dynamically execute a function. In your example:

```
 loop(x->funcByName("test_" + string(x))(), 1..100)
```

For more information about `functionByName`, see the [DolphinDB official documentation.](https://dolphindb.com/help/FunctionsandCommands/FunctionReferences/f/funcByName.html)